# Convert imageurl to base64 in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

My Code is like

```
var url = "http://160.114.10.17:98/Upload/OEMLogo/ac3940d2-6e5c-45d5-9296-8387874c499a_Logo.png"



function getBase64FromImageUrl(url) {

var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

img.onload = function () {
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = this.width;
canvas.height = this.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var url = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
};

img.src = url;

}
```

When i try to convert image to base64 this error will fire in consol

Access to Image at 'http://160.114.10.17:98/Upload/OEMLogo/ac3940d2-6e5c-45d5-9296-8387874c499a_Logo.png' from origin 'http://localhost:8383' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access.

Please help me. anybody have idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are not convert image problem.

It's CORS Problem are you allow CORS on you server side?

https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: yes i allow CORS on my server side. but its server folder path.